# How to launch youtube from flutter app android?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to make the container click lead to a specific youtube url which should open in the the youtube app and not in webview inside the app.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

Comment: url launcher opens in the browser

Comment: try this https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_appavailability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add in `pubspec.yaml`:

```
dependecies:
  url_launcher: ^5.4.2
```

add this in your code:

```
LaunchUrl('https://www.youtube.com');//or any link you want
```

Answer (score 2):

You should look into the package [android_intent](https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent). Basically it will resolve the url if it has been defined as a valid link for an application in your android parameters (which is enabled by default for youtube).

**Code Sample**

```dart
AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
   action: 'action_view',
   data: url,
);
await intent.launch();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use package [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) with the function below:

```
launchUrl(
                Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${youtubeID}"),
                mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
```